# Turn off infuriating Xcode editor completions

Tags: xcode, substitution

I type

> false

and Xcode substitutes that to

> FALSE

(.swift file).
Now which of the multitude of autocomplete checkboxes in text editor settings
I need to uncheck to stop that?
So that ESC sequence still works.

Or I'd rephrase this as: what is the difference between "Suggest completions while typing" and "Enable type-over completions"?